# Cannot find class [org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue]

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core
http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core-5.5.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Activemq connection factory -->
   <!--  <bean id="amqConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
    </bean> -->

<jee:jndi-lookup id="amqConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/activemq/ConnectionFactoryAVT" />
<jee:jndi-lookup id="tripQueue" jndi-name="java:/activemq/queue_trip" />
    <!-- ConnectionFactory Definition -->
    <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="amqConnectionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!--  Default Destination Queue Definition-->
    <bean id="defaultDestination" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="queue.trip"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- JmsTemplate Definition -->
    <bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
        <property name="defaultDestination" ref="tripQueue" />
    </bean>

       <!-- Message Sender Definition -->
    <bean id="messageSender" class="com.proxy.vcg.b.beans.JMSQueueSenderForTrip" />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.proxy.vcg"></context:component-scan>  
</beans>
```

This is the bean config xml for JMS ActiveMQ simple spring java project.
While deploying I get the following exception and deployment fails, I'm using Jboss 6.1, and I am using spring version 3.

```
Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue] for bean with name 'defaultDestination' defined in URL [vfs:/C:/Tools/jboss-eap-6.1.0/jboss-eap-6.1/bin/content/RestGateway.war/WEB-INF/lib/Proxy-7.0.jar/jmsTrip.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue from [Module "deployment.RestGateway.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
```

Any help? Many thanks!!!

Following is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.fish.net</groupId>
    <artifactId>AV</artifactId>
    <name>AVTWER</name>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>

        <module>RestGateway</module>
        <module>Proxy</module>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>




    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Test dependencies that might be used by children -->

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>catalina</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.43</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JavaEE compile-time dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>

        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId> <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId> 
            <version>1.0b</version> </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.9</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>junit</groupId> <artifactId>junit</artifactId> 
            <version>4.8.1</version> <scope>test</scope> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlunit</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>
                <dependency> 
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> 
                        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId> 
                        <version>4.2.11.Final</version> 
                </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring -->



        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
            <artifactId>wmq-jmsra</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.1.9-reconnect-configured</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Graphite Monitoring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wirelesscar.statistics</groupId>
            <artifactId>statistics-base</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Quartz job scheduler -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ini4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>ini4j</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.volvo.vgt.avt.map.component</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapcomponent</artifactId>
            <version>27</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.181</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.8</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <!-- <exclusion> <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId> </exclusion> 
                    <exclusion> <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId> </exclusion> -->
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <atomikos.version>3.8.0</atomikos.version>
        <spring.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <derby.version>10.8.1.2</derby.version>
        <el.version>1.0</el.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.1</slf4j.version>
        <main.basedir>${project.parent.basedir}</main.basedir>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `activemq-all` dependency scope from `provided` to `compile` (or remove the scope tag) to have the .jar with the class you miss in your `WEB-INF/lib`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
<artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
<version>5.14.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Adding this dependency worked for me!